# Phlyrestfully Example not working - 404 error

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having trouble running Phlyrestfully based on the example from the documentation.
http://phlyrestfully.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics/example.html
I've started this as a new zend skeleton and created routes plus listeners. 
I getting a 404 error at all times. No other errors.

```
return array(
'phlyrestfully' => array(
    'resources' => array(
        'Paste\ApiController' => array(
            'identifier'              => 'Pastes',
            'listener'                => 'Paste\PasteResourceListener',
            'resource_identifiers'    => array('PasteResource'),
            'collection_http_options' => array('get', 'post'),
            'collection_name'         => 'pastes',
            'page_size'               => 10,
            'resource_http_options'   => array('get'),
            'route_name'              => 'paste/api',
            ),
        ),
    ),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'paste' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/paste',
'controller' => 'Paste\PasteController', // for the web UI
),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'api' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'      => '/api/pastes[/:id]',
                        'controller' => 'Paste\ApiController',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )),
'view_manager' => array(
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy'
        ))
);
```

The Listener file:

```
namespace Paste;

use PhlyRestfully\Exception\CreationException;
use PhlyRestfully\Exception\DomainException;
use PhlyRestfully\ResourceEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;

class PasteResourceListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate
{
protected $persistence;

public function __construct(PersistenceInterface $persistence)
{
    $this->persistence = $persistence;
}

public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('create', array($this, 'onCreate'));
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('fetch', array($this, 'onFetch'));
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('fetchAll', array($this, 'onFetchAll'));
}

public function onCreate(ResourceEvent $e)
{
    $data  = $e->getParam('data');
    $paste = $this->persistence->save($data);
    if (!$paste) {
        throw new CreationException();
    }
    return $paste;
}

public function onFetch(ResourceEvent $e)
{
    $id = $e->getParam('id');
    $paste = $this->persistence->fetch($id);
    if (!$paste) {
        throw new DomainException('Paste not found', 404);
    }
    return $paste;
}

public function onFetchAll(ResourceEvent $e)
{
    return $this->persistence->fetchAll();
}
}
```

Interface file:

```
namespace Paste;

interface PersistenceInterface
{
public function save(array $data);
public function fetch($id);
public function fetchAll();
}
```

Model file:

```
namespace Paste;

class Module
{
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array('factories' => array(
        'Paste\PasteResourceListener' => function ($services) {
            $persistence = $services->get('Paste\PersistenceInterface');
            return new PasteResourceListener($persistence);
        },
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: How about opening an issue on Matthews GitRepository? He may probably the only one able to help with such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation,

> First, I’ll define an interface for persistence. I’m doing this in
>   order to focus on the pieces related to the API; how you actually
>   persist your data is completely up to you.

So, you have to implement the persistence layer yourself. The example won't work with just copy/pasting. Create a class that implements the `PersistenceInterface` and inject that in your listener.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array('factories' => array(
        'Paste\PasteResourceListener' => function ($services) {
            $persistence = $services->get('Your\Persistence\Class');
            return new PasteResourceListener($persistence);
        },
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller config of the route belongs in the defaults. The route is matched, but the controller is **notfound**. The original *Pastes* example from Matthew's PhlyRestfully documentation is missing this.

```
'router' => array('routes' => array(
    'paste' => array(
        'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/paste',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Paste\PasteController', // for the web UI
            )
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'api' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'      => '/api/pastes[/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Paste\ApiController',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```